# connection string for sql server 2008 using smart device and Visual Basic

Tags: sql-server

just doing a little app for a Smart Device on Visual Basic 2008,I have made a module to control the connection which is linked to a regular Form and inside the module I have declare my connection string but is just not working.

#### Declare like this:

```
Public conn As New SqlConnection("Data Source=myServer;Initial Catalog=myDataBase;Integrated Security=SSPI")
```

#### little sub routine using to try the connection:

```
Public Sub connect()
    Try
        conn.Open()
        Form1.lblmensajes1.Text = "CONNECTED..."
    Catch ex As Exception
         Form1.lblmensajes1.Text = "NOT CONNECTED"
         Form1.TextBox1.Text = ex.ToString

    End Try
 End Sub
```

The exception:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, TdsParserState state) 
    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, TdsParserState state)
    System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning()
     System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Connect(String host, SqlInternalConnection connHandler, Int32 timeout) 
     System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OpenAndLogin()
     System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection..ctor(SqlConnection connection, Hashtable connectionOptions)
     System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open() en SmartDeviceProject1.conection.connect() 
    SmartDeviceProject1.Form1.btnconect_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
    System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)

System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WnProc(WM wm, Int32 wParam, Int32 lParam) 
System.Windows.Forms.Control._InternalWnProc(WM wm, Int32 wParam, Int32 lParam)
 Microsoft.AGL.Forms.EVL.EnterMainLoop(IntPtr hwnMain)
 System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form fm)
 SmartDeviceProject1.Form1.Main()
```

Comment: "*just not working*" doesn't tell us anything. Get the message from the exception and tell us what it is.

Comment: What is the value of `ex.Message`?

Comment: I know, sorry, the reason I did not provide the ex.message is because it wont let me get it on the clipboard, because the message is displayed on the little emulator and the window inside the emulator it does not give you the chance to copy the message, but will give a try once again,thanks for the help

Comment: Then just write it down.

Comment: working on it, thanks

Comment: this is what Im getting: plz be aware I have devided in peaces because the comment option will not let me put the hole exceptin in one comment...en System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, TdsParserState state)
en System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, TdsParserState state)
en System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning()

Comment: continue: en System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Connect(String host, SqlInternalConnection connHandler, Int32 timeout)
en System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OpenAndLogin()
en System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection..ctor(SqlConnection connection, Hashtable connectionOptions)
en System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
en SmartDeviceProject1.conection.connect()
en SmartDeviceProject1.Form1.btnconect_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
en System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
en System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)

Comment: continue:
en System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WnProc(WM wm, Int32 wParam, Int32 lParam)
en System.Windows.Forms.Control._InternalWnProc(WM wm, Int32 wParam, Int32 lParam)
en Microsoft.AGL.Forms.EVL.EnterMainLoop(IntPtr hwnMain)
en System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form fm)
en SmartDeviceProject1.Form1.Main().....there you go, this is what the execption error is showing,thanks you guys

Comment: plz I have added the ex.message and no reply, please help...

Comment: @MarioNic Try **editing** your original post, rather than posting these as comments. It's hard to read the exceptions in the comments, which will be hidden by default.

Comment: @MarioNic If you can share the Image of your exception. We have to read your exception. Its just hard to get what you posted

Comment: Also: that's the stack trace, **not** the exception message.

Comment: @MarioNic, Can you able to connect to the Database ?? have you got chance to check the link, i answered below. Connectionstrings have all type of connections.

Comment: @goofyui , yes I saw the answer,thx, the samples are ok, the issue still about not connecting in real time as some one else told me, it seems that a mobile device app will not be connected to its DB in real time,it needs an API to act as a bridge between the app and the DB,what do you think about that?

Comment: If you have a Compact Edition Database which the Database located in the device itself. You can go with CD Edition SQL Query. If you are using a webservice to connect to the SQL Database running in the Server. You need a webservice or api url to set the connection

Comment: thanks @gooofyui, Im trying the webservice now but its giving error as well,Im used to c# not visual basic which is the one Im using to make the web service. The error actually is giving me another question for stackoverflow LoL,probably I will have to post a new question later on.  Any sample code using DataAdapter for a web service connecting to SQL server in Visual Basic guys,thanks

Answer (score 0):

http://www.connectionstrings.com/

Compact Edition

Data Source=myServerAddress;Initial Catalog=myDataBase;Integrated Security=SSPI;
User ID=myDomain\myUsername;Password=myPassword;